# Multiple google places request function (dispensary locator)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a tiny Google maps javascript v3 store locator that I'm using to show locations for about 5 stores - my question is if there's a smarter way for me to make the places requests and info windows than having 5 separate ones like so:

```
  //places request #1
        //place ID for first location
        servicedcd.getDetails({placeId: 'ChIJy_YmBMEMIocRZF8r5wPFMYU'}, 
            function(place, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         map: map,
                        position: place.geometry.location,
                        icon: 'img/pillicon.jpg'});
                    targetLoc = place.geometry.location;
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                         dcdLoc = place.geometry.location;
                        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong class="dmap-title">' + place.name + '</strong></div><br>' +
                        '<div class="dmap-address">' + place.formatted_address + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="dmap-phone">' + place.formatted_phone_number + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="dmap-rating">' + place.rating + '</div>' +                                  
                        '<button onClick="getDirNew(dcdLoc);"><h3>Directions to ' + place.name + '</h3></button>' + 
                        '<a href="' + place.website + '"><h4>Website</h4></a>' + 
                        + 'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                        place.formatted_address + '</div>');
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                        console.log('new dcd geo loc: ' + place.geometry.location);
                    });
                }
          });



//places request #2
            //place ID for second location
            servicedcd.getDetails({placeId: 'ChIJy_YmBMEMIocRZF8r5wPFMYU'}, 
                function(place, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             map: map,
                            position: place.geometry.location,
                            icon: 'img/pillicon.jpg'});
                        targetLoc = place.geometry.location;
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                             dcdLoc = place.geometry.location;
                            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong class="dmap-title">' + place.name + '</strong></div><br>' +
                            '<div class="dmap-address">' + place.formatted_address + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="dmap-phone">' + place.formatted_phone_number + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="dmap-rating">' + place.rating + '</div>' +                                  
                            '<button onClick="getDirNew(dcdLoc);"><h3>Directions to ' + place.name + '</h3></button>' + 
                            '<a href="' + place.website + '"><h4>Website</h4></a>' + 
                            + 'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                            place.formatted_address + '</div>');
                            infowindow.open(map, this);
                            console.log('new dcd geo loc: ' + place.geometry.location);
                        });
                    }
              });
```

and so on.  I know its bad.  I have it up for testing on AWS at

http://52.10.135.217/

if anyone cares to take a look and give me advice

Thanks very much

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, not a link to an external site that will go away (or get fixed and no longer display the issue)

Comment: This question might be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've currently got an anonymous function that you're passing as your second parameter to `servicedcd.getDetails`:

However what you could do is create that as a separate function, which you then just pass by name, e.g.

```
function addMarker(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location,
            icon: 'img/pillicon.jpg'});
        targetLoc = place.geometry.location;
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             dcdLoc = place.geometry.location;
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong class="dmap-title">' + place.name + '</strong></div><br>' +
            '<div class="dmap-address">' + place.formatted_address + '</div>' +
            '<div class="dmap-phone">' + place.formatted_phone_number + '</div>' +
            '<div class="dmap-rating">' + place.rating + '</div>' +                                  
            '<button onClick="getDirNew(dcdLoc);"><h3>Directions to ' + place.name + '</h3></button>' + 
            '<a href="' + place.website + '"><h4>Website</h4></a>' + 
            + 'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
            place.formatted_address + '</div>');
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            console.log('new dcd geo loc: ' + place.geometry.location);
        });
    }
}

servicedcd.getDetails({placeId: 'ChIJy_YmBMEMIocRZF8r5wPFMYU'}, addMarker);
```

Then if the only thing that differs is the place IDs, you could put those into an array that you loop over:

```
placeIDs = [
    'ChIJy_YmBMEMIocRZF8r5wPFMYU',
    'ID 2',
    'ID 3'
];

for (var i = 0; i < placeIDs.length; i++) {
    servicedcd.getDetails({placeId: placeIDs[i]}, addMarker);
}
```

Comment: Sweet thanks Duncan I'm gonna do exactly that - your answer is exactly the guidance I needed